# How to redirect a subdomain to the main domain so I can use an SSL certificate?

Tags: apache, https, multiple-domains

I have an apache server hosting with one IP address hosting a www and a 'sub' domain using `<virtualhost>`.  That worked fine until I needed an EV certificate which works on only 1 domain.  It can't be used until I merge these two domains. The subdomain is a directory of the www domain.

I can remove the subdomain by removing the appropriate `<virtualhost>` section. 
How do I redirect traffic from sub.domain.com to `www.domain.com/subdir`?

Comment: One of the best files ever: `.htaccess`. It's magic ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a virtual host set up, the easiest way to implement the redirect is going to be to replace the virtual host configuration rather than remove it.  A virtual host that only redirects has a very simple configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.example.com
    RedirectPermanent / http://www.example.com/subdir
</VirtualHost>
```

Once you do that, your SSL certificate can be used on your entire `www`.